# How do I disable rebasing when I call git pull?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

Each time I have a commit diverged with the `origin/master` and I call git pull, it tries to rebase, which I have lots of trouble with. But if I call `git fetch` and then `git merge origin/master` everything is ok. How can I set the default pull behaviour to merge without rebasing?

Comment: you couldn't google this?

Comment: I looked up the git pull documentation and it has an option to disable rebase. Seems pretty clear. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: after reading the rebase part from the page you gave and googling, i found out that i need `autosetupmerge = always`, instead of writing something about rebase. Thank you!

Comment: git remote update and then your remote branches is updated and you can do a merge or a rebase manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the expected pull action for this branch

```
git config branch.never.rebase false
```

You can also make sure any new branch is rebased on pull

```
git config branch.autoSetupRebase never
```

See both settings in [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command to undo rebase:

```sh
git rebase --abort
```

Before running this command, you should save your latest commit.

Answer (score -2):

its a fetch, btw.

```
git fetch <remote> <branch>
```

Comment: sorry but i don't want to fetch, I just want `git pull` not to do rebase. I don't know how, but on my other computer it works without rebasing, and on this one it does rebase